# Extract AutoMapper source name from custom maps via ForMember

Tags: c#, lambda, automapper

I have successfully extracted simple source/destination pairs from an existing Automapper TypeMap using this code:

```
private MemberInfo getSource(Type destinationType, string destinationPropertyname)
{
  TypeMap map = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps()
                      .Where(m => m.DestinationType.Equals(destinationType))
                      .First();
  IEnumerable<PropertyMap> properties = 
      map.GetPropertyMaps()
         .Where(p => p.DestinationProperty
                      .Name
                      .Equals(destinationPropertyname, 
                              StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
  PropertyMap sourceProperty = properties.First();
  IMemberGetter mg = sourceProperty.GetSourceValueResolvers()
                                   .Cast<IMemberGetter>()
                                   .First();

  return mg.MemberInfo;
}
```

However, when I add custom column mappings like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewModel>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Cell, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CellPhone))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Email, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EmailAddress));
```

...  the source part of the mapping is not available from `GetSourceResolvers()` that I can tell.

I appreciate any guidance you have.

Thank you.

-Jessy Houle

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need this information from AutoMapper?  What scenario are you using AutoMapper for that you need to dig into it's internals from the outside?

Comment: Patrick, I'm trying to map validation results from the domain layer down to the viewmodel layer.  Straight auto-name mapping is easy retrieve, but anything beyond this is difficult to get the mappings (EG: formula mapping, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Is this along the lines of what you wanted?

```
var map = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<Customer, CustomerViewModel>();

foreach( var propertMap in map.GetPropertyMaps() )
{
    var dest = propertMap.DestinationProperty.MemberInfo;
    var source = propertMap.SourceMember;
}
```